# extract elements from a list

Tags: python, list

I have a file from which i am reading into a list.In this list I need to separate few fields 
if it has R in that line then the list1 should have the following output
Required output as a list:

```
 [48998 18:45:44 qp32,   
    49005 00:44:23  qp32,
    49047 312:33:0  qp128]
```

if it has Q in that line then another list2 should have the remaining entries as output

The file is as follows:

job.txt-

```
48998.tyrone-clustergic1_nwgsmbupi18:45:44Rqp32  
48999.tyrone-clustergic2_nwgsmbupi0Qbatch  
49005.tyrone-cluster...01R-1849-01_2mcbkss00:44:23Rqp32  
49032.tyrone-clustergaussian_top.shchemraja0Qqp32  
8788.tyrone-clusterjet_egridasevelt312:33:0Rqp128  
49052.tyrone-clustercase3sqTS1e-4mecvamsi0Qqp32  
49053.tyrone-cluster...01R-1850-01_1mcbkss0Qbatch      
49054.tyrone-cluster...01R-1850-01_2mcbkss0Qbatch          
8987.tyrone-clusterjob256icrtaraf0Qqp256          
49073.tyrone-clusterjob256icrtaraf0Qbatch
```

till now i have tried

`list1 = [(s.split(' ')[0]) for s in mylist if 'R' in s]` #for R and similar code for Q

```
o/p :  ['48999.tyrone-clustergic2_nwgsmbupi0Qbatch', '49032.tyrone-clustergaussian_top.shchemraja0Qqp32', '49052.tyrone-clustercase3sqTS1e-4mecvamsi0Qqp32', '49053.tyrone-cluster...01R-1850-01_1mcbkss0Qbatch', '49054.tyrone-cluster...01R-1850-01_2mcbkss0Qbatch']
```

but the output should be in the format as I had specified in the beginning

Comment: Just iterate content with if 'R' in line: ... elif 'Q' in line: ... ?

Comment: Can you post your attempt/code?

Comment: What is your question? Also, your statement is not very clear. Please clarify.

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: Sorry...i have edited the question

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('job.txt') as f:
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    for line in f.readlines():
        if 'R' in line:
           list1.append(line)  #you might want to format this line as per your requirements using regex
        else:
           list2.append(line)

print list1
print list2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
job_file_handle = open("job.txt", "r") # open a handle on the file
job_lines = job_file_handle.readlines() # read in all of the lines
job_file_handle.close() # close the file handle

for line in job_lines:
    if line.split("R") > line.split("Q"): 
        processRLine(line)

    else
        processQLine(line)
```